# Scale with CGAffineTransform and set the anchor

Tags: iphone, ios, scaling, cgaffinetransform

If I understand correctly scaling a `UIView` with `CGAffineTransform` anchors the transformation to its center.

In particular:

```
self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
NSLog(@"%f;%f;%f;%f", self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
```

Prints:

```
-50;-50;200;200
```

How do you create a CGAffineTransform scale that uses a specific anchor point (say 0;0)?

Comment: It's weird, i'm on iOS 7 and it doesn't scale from the center, but it scales from the top left... Even if I set anchorpoint to (0.5, 0.5) it doesn't scale from center. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: @VanDuTran I found that using `CATransform3D` on the view's `layer` behaves correctly and obeys `anchorPoint`. Try that instead of using `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`, which somehow constrains the view to the window top and left bounds.

Comment: @JonathanLin I use layer with CATransform3D which also with no luck on iOS 7

Answer (score 73, accepted):

(a)

Scale and then translate?

Something like :

```
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, width/2, height/2);
self.transform = t;
```

(b)

Set the anchor point (which is probably what you want really)

```
[self layer].anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
```

(c)

Set the center again to make sure it's in the same place?

```
CGPoint center = self.center;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
self.center = center;
```

Comment: Method (a) prints 50;50;200;200 with a scale of 2. Will test method (b) shortly, but wouldn't that affect all transforms? Might cause side-effects.

Comment: That's because the first scale transform will affect the second. The order you apply transforms matters ;) And if it's just a translation you're trying to do then my not just set the frame/bounds/center to the new position?

Comment: Interestingly, method (a) prints 0;0;300;300 with a scale of 3 and --50;-50;400;400 with a scale of 4. Maybe there's something missing?

Comment: (and yes, you're right about (b) affecting all translations on that object - that might not be what you wanted!)

Comment: Of course I can change the position manually but mostly I want to understand CGAffineTransform better. :)

Comment: Don't forget that if you translate up 100px but your transform has a scale of 2 already then you're actually translating up 200px - you have to compensate for your scale factor when you decide how far to translate!

Comment: Take a look at this article : http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html - I found it very helpful!

Comment: After a few tests it appears the transform for a (0,0) anchor point is: double scale = 2;
    double translateX = self.frame.size.width * (scale - 1)/2/scale;
    double translateY = self.frame.size.height * (scale - 1)/2/scale;
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
    t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, translateX, translateY);
    self.transform = t;

Comment: I have asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495592/when-i-make-zoom-center-is-shifted-to-the-left-bottom, and I have tried your answers but they don't work for me. I have to scale a video image with the same center.

Comment: Number (c) is not working, it appears as if the center is the same, do the transformation takes some time to make effect?

Answer (score 5):

This is the way I found the scale a view while keeping it's origin in place (0,0) in **Swift5**

```
func animate() {
    myView.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -0.5, y: -0.5)
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.3, curve: .easeOut) {
        self.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.25, y: 0.25)
    }
}

extension UIView {
func setAnchorPoint(_ point: CGPoint) {
    var newPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * point.x, y: bounds.size.height * point.y)
    var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * layer.anchorPoint.x, y: bounds.size.height * layer.anchorPoint.y);

    newPoint = newPoint.applying(transform)
    oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(transform)

    var position = layer.position

    position.x -= oldPoint.x
    position.x += newPoint.x

    position.y -= oldPoint.y
    position.y += newPoint.y

    layer.position = position
    layer.anchorPoint = point
}
}
```

credit to [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-change-a-views-anchor-point-without-moving-it)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly #import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and then set the anchor  points of your view:

```
   [[self layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Comment: That would change the anchor point for all transforms. I would like to create a scale transform with a specific anchor point.

Comment: CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 2, 2);
  self.transform = tr;
  self.center = CGPointMake(0,0);